# Variable returning 0 when database indicates it should be -1

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9

Working in Magento, I'm currently trying to amend our product table which appears in the sales confirmation emails, so that if the product was out of stock when the customer placed the order, the product lead time gets displayed (and i  f the product was in stock, an in stock message gets displayed).

I'm running into an issue where from what I can see a quantity variable should be -1, but is actually 0:

```
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->load(Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku($this->getSku($_item)));
        echo $stock->getQty();
        if($stock->getQty() >= 0){
            echo 'in stock message';
        }
        else {
            echo 'out of stock message';
        } ?>
```

The Qty field in the cataloginventory_stock_item table is -1.0000, however echo $stock->getQty(); prints 0.0000 (as does a var_dump of $stock).

I think I'm calling getQty() from the right place/corresponding table to the one I'm looking at in phpMyAdmin...

var_dump($stock) returns the following:

```
 object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item)#861 (20) { ["_minSaleQtyCache":"Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item":private]=> array(0) { } ["_qtyIncrements":protected]=> NULL ["_eventPrefix":protected]=> string(27) "cataloginventory_stock_item" ["_eventObject":protected]=> string(4) "item" ["_productInstance":protected]=> NULL ["_customerGroupId":protected]=> NULL ["_processIndexEvents":protected]=> bool(true) ["_resourceName":protected]=> string(27) "cataloginventory/stock_item" ["_resource":protected]=> NULL ["_resourceCollectionName":protected]=> string(38) "cataloginventory/stock_item_collection" ["_cacheTag":protected]=> bool(false) ["_dataSaveAllowed":protected]=> bool(true) ["_isObjectNew":protected]=> NULL ["_data":protected]=> array(28) { ["item_id"]=> string(5) "13931" ["product_id"]=> string(5) "14032" ["stock_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["qty"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["min_qty"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["use_config_min_qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["is_qty_decimal"]=> string(1) "0" ["backorders"]=> string(1) "1" ["use_config_backorders"]=> string(1) "0" ["min_sale_qty"]=> string(6) "1.0000" ["use_config_min_sale_qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["max_sale_qty"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["use_config_max_sale_qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["is_in_stock"]=> string(1) "1" ["low_stock_date"]=> string(19) "2016-08-15 10:38:30" ["notify_stock_qty"]=> NULL ["use_config_notify_stock_qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["manage_stock"]=> string(1) "1" ["use_config_manage_stock"]=> string(1) "0" ["stock_status_changed_auto"]=> string(1) "0" ["use_config_qty_increments"]=> string(1) "1" ["qty_increments"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["use_config_enable_qty_inc"]=> string(1) "1" ["enable_qty_increments"]=> string(1) "0" ["is_decimal_divided"]=> string(1) "0" ["type_id"]=> string(6) "simple" ["stock_status_changed_automatically"]=> string(1) "0" ["use_config_enable_qty_increments"]=> string(1) "1" } ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=> bool(false) ["_origData":protected]=> array(28) { ["item_id"]=> string(5) "13931" ["product_id"]=> string(5) "14032" ["stock_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["qty"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["min_qty"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["use_config_min_qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["is_qty_decimal"]=> string(1) "0" ["backorders"]=> string(1) "1" ["use_config_backorders"]=> string(1) "0" ["min_sale_qty"]=> string(6) "1.0000" ["use_config_min_sale_qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["max_sale_qty"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["use_config_max_sale_qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["is_in_stock"]=> string(1) "1" ["low_stock_date"]=> string(19) "2016-08-15 10:38:30" ["notify_stock_qty"]=> NULL ["use_config_notify_stock_qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["manage_stock"]=> string(1) "1" ["use_config_manage_stock"]=> string(1) "0" ["stock_status_changed_auto"]=> string(1) "0" ["use_config_qty_increments"]=> string(1) "1" ["qty_increments"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["use_config_enable_qty_inc"]=> string(1) "1" ["enable_qty_increments"]=> string(1) "0" ["is_decimal_divided"]=> string(1) "0" ["type_id"]=> string(6) "simple" ["stock_status_changed_automatically"]=> string(1) "0" ["use_config_enable_qty_increments"]=> string(1) "1" } ["_idFieldName":protected]=> NULL ["_isDeleted":protected]=> bool(false) ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=> array(2) { ["stock_status_changed_automatically"]=> string(25) "stock_status_changed_auto" ["use_config_enable_qty_increments"]=> string(25) "use_config_enable_qty_inc" } ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=> array(4) { ["stock_status_changed_automatically"]=> string(25) "stock_status_changed_auto" ["use_config_enable_qty_increments"]=> string(25) "use_config_enable_qty_inc" ["stock_status_changed_auto"]=> string(34) "stock_status_changed_automatically" ["use_config_enable_qty_inc"]=> string(32) "use_config_enable_qty_increments" } }
```

Comment: Why should a `$stock->getQty()` with result `0` echo a `in stock message`? What means a stock quantity of 0? What is the diff. from -1?

Comment: If you `var_dump $stock->getData();` do you see the stock level?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions this processes after the customer places the order, meaning the stock quantities will all be 1 less than before, so the stock quantity will be 0 if the product was in stock when the order was placed - if the product wasn't in stock the quantity would be -1 (as we have magento set up to allow back orders).

Comment: @DouglasRadburn see my recent edit for var_dump($stock) - it has qty with a value of 0, however the database table makes me think it should be -1.0000

Comment: @Edward based on your `var_dump` are you sure `item_id` 13931 has `qty` -1.0000. Please check it again. or just get id like this `$id = $stock->getId();
echo "<pre>";print_r($id);die;` and check in your table `cataloginventory_stock_item` for `qty` value of this `item_id` which you get in print

Comment: @Vky item_id 13931 does not however there were 2 products which I have been testing which absolutely have stock quantities of -1.  Apologies, 13931 was potentially a bad example, I just copied the first product vardump in the test email I made

Comment: Ok i tried your code in magento root / php file. with starting `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(393);
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->load(Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku($product->getSku()));` and after this your code goes. And tried changing qty of 393 product in table `cataloginventory_stock_item` and i am getting corrent result like -1.0000 or whatever qty is in table.

Comment: @Vky the cataloginventory_stock_item table?  This is very strange as I've checked this for 2 products, each one has -1 in qty in the table/back end of magento, however each returns 0 from getQty()

Comment: Yes `cataloginventory_stock_item` table